# Implementing Transaction Status Indicators and Block Explorer Links in Solana Applications

Tags: transaction, development, confirmation

I'm looking to add transaction status indicators to my Solana application, indicating whether a transaction is confirmed or not, along with links to the block explorer for further verification. I'm wondering if there's an easy way to accomplish this within the Solana ecosystem. If not, could someone provide guidance on how to implement this feature? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to confirm a transaction, you can use `connection.confirmTransaction` https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/f9509c77dd6ec92357edbbe18acbb76c5a33e4b2/packages/library-legacy/src/connection.ts#L3735

And then most explorers provide a page to view a transaction based on the signature. Here's an example from the Solana Explorer, where you can provide the signature after `tx/`, ie: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2KjqNx9L7WD4yiKrG8UABX6NbK4KitA39TG2qYX2BjTtjwbx2Za4gLdiNSV4nziW7QdnsokfE3STa6S6GpPpyKbc